# Showing method "parameter names" in objective-c

Tags: objective-c, macos, nsdictionary

How can I get the parameter names to show up when making a method in objective-c?

For example, I notice that NSDictionary defines it's method like this:

```
- (void)setValue:(id)valueforKey:(NSString *)key;
```

But it actually shows up in use as this:

```
[dictionary setValue:@"myValue" forKey:@"myKey"];
```

If I define the same stub above in my header file, it shows up as this in use:

```
[self setValue:@"My value" :@"My Key"]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing a space:

```
- (void)setValue:(id)value forKey:(NSString *)key;
//                        ^ HERE
```

The signature that you provided uses identifier `valueforKey` as the name of the first formal parameter, and an empty segment for the `key` parameter.